# Spring Boot and Angular 5 in the same repository, would Travis work?

Tags: spring, angular, continuous-integration

I have a repository in GitHub which contains a Spring Boot project and an Angular 5 project, and I was wondering if I can make a travis config file for those projects at the same time. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, I have the same configuration working with Travis. I have both projects in the root (pom.xml and package.json) because I need it for Heroku. This is part of my travis.yml:

```
deploy:
language: java
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
before_install:
  - npm i -g npm@latest
script:
  - npm run lint:ci
  - npm run build:prod
```